# Database table schem advise

Tags: java, mysql, database, relational-database, database-schema

Good day , i have the following project which i have created for myself and i will implement by making use of java and MySQL . However , I would like some advise on the database tables.

From what i tried to design , my tables will be structured in this way :

Table Lecture : Lecture_Name , Lecture_ID(PK) , Lecture_Password , File_Question .

Table Student : Std_Name , Std_Number(PK) , File_Question(FK) , Std_Marks.

Is it the correct table or am i missing something crucial?

any help will be gladly appreciated.

A lecturer requires a program that administers multiple-choice tests.

The lecturer would prepare questions for the Test Bank as a text file.  The format would be:
Category            (One of 4.  For example Networking)
Question            (One or more lines)
Four alternative answers    (Labelled a., b., c., d.  One or more lines, each.)
Blank line
The correct option      (a., b., c. or d.  Only one option would be correct)
Two Blank lines

A user will log on to the system either as a lecturer, or as a student.  The user will have to enter a username and a password.

If the user is a lecturer, he/she will be asked
    To enter the name of the text file containing the new questions

The program would:
    Read the data from the text file.

If the user is a student, he/she would conduct a self-test by:
    Setting the categories (one, some, or all, of the 4 available categories).

The program would:
    Randomly select the required number of questions from the category (ies) chosen.
    Present the questions, together with their alternative answers, one at a time.
    Allow the student to select only one answer.
    Tell the student if he answered correctly or not.
    Present the next question.
    Give the student the results of the test expressed as the percentage of correct answers, after      the student has answered all the questions.

Your minimum functional units are:
i.  teacher should be able to upload a file
ii. student should be able to select and view questions from his interface
iii.    student should be able to select and answer questions from his interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest some changes

- Lecture table should have only attributes of lecture. Keep information of question in seperate table. It will help you to grow your application. 
  For eg if there are more than one question file for a lecture. If that is not the case then lecture table seems fine.
- Student's table needs some changes as what will happen if some students take multiple tests.
  Try to keep information of one real world entity in one table.
- Keep student info in Table Student : Std_Name , Std_Number(PK)
- create seperate table marks:Std_Number(FK)  File_Question(FK) , Std_Marks.

For storing the questions from lecturer

- How about table for them and providing teacher with interface to provide questions of the test too.
- You will also be creating lecturer table right?

Comment: yes i will be creating it too. thanks a lot for your advise, will try to bring these changes

Comment: the student will take multiple tests, but once at the time. The lecture will just be uploading the textfiles.

Comment: if there are multiple tests for a student then try to keep student info and student marks seperate.